# Send javascript array with strings to php action

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, image

I want to send an array with image strings to my php action. This is what I do so far:

```
$('#savepdf').click(function() {
    var imagesarray = new Array();
    var count = 4;
    var quizid = <?php echo json_encode($quizid); ?>;
    for (var i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        var chart = Highcharts.charts[i];
        var canvasname;
        if(i == 0){
            canvasname = "canvas";
        }
        else{
            canvasname = "canvas" + i;
        }

        // get highcharts
        canvg(document.getElementById(canvasname), chart.getSVG())

        var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasname);
        var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

        imagesarray[i] = img;
    }

    imagesarray = JSON.stringify(imagesarray);

    // AJAX CALL TO ACTION
    $.download('/results/savepdf','quizid=' + quizid + '&image=' + imagesarray);
});
```

The array that I send looks like this:

> ["data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAlgAAAGQCAYAAAByNR6YAAAgAElEQ…197b1kPfJ5y3guHO4WLEyAAAECBAgcEFjz7y+zZJ6ttf8GC0YA4ro/bucAAAAASUVORK5CYII=","data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAlgAAAGQCAYAAAByNR6YAAAgAElEQ…9v2cl0YeqeBTqMAAIIIIAAAgMINO3aT3a+sfNxGIa7fwBwOTGmIk2OYgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==","data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAlgAAAGQCAYAAAByNR6YAAAgAElEQ…xdLNBhIkAEiAARIAJEIA8I7FRlf1T/XlD/hhcoUOCv/we6Hn4A9659wwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==","data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAlgAAAGQCAYAAAByNR6YAAAgAElEQ…BdGOlYwAkjASSABJAAEkACBgm8UI89qf6sUX9GRIkS5cr/AFfL9D3Dad7CAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"]

In my PHP action I do the following:

```
if(isset($_POST['quizid']))
     $quizid = $_POST['quizid'];
if(isset($_POST['image']))
     $image = $_POST['image'];

var_dump(json_decode($image));
```

The dump just shows "NULL". When I do this :

```
var_dump($image);
```

I just get : `string(1) "["`

Comment: `$_POST["image"]` is simply not valid JSON (that's why you get `null`). Can you add `encodeURIComponent` to `imagesarray` before you post it?

Comment: Won't you have to use `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`? I don't know the `$.download` method so I'm not sure, but it looks like a query string to me. (Of course it might also be the encoded post format)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to:

> ```
> imagesarray = encodeURIComponent( JSON.stringify(imagesarray) );
> ```

**UPDATE**

and in php use

> ```
> $image = json_decode(urldecode($_POST['image']));
> ```

Comment: When I check my data in php I have this: "%5B%22data%3Aimage%2Fpng%3Bbase64%2CiV, Do you know how I can encode the dollar signs? (special chars)

Comment: in php try `$image = json_decode(urldecode($_POST['image']));`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the `$.download` method. Presumably it is an AJAX extension that allows for file downloads. I can guess how it probably works.

The problem is that you are not sending a valid HTTP request. JSON needs to be escaped to be sent over HTTP. You could do this yourself using `encodeURIComponent`, or you could let jQuery's [`$.param`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param) method handle it for you.

```
var data = $.param({
    quizid: quizid,
    image: imagesarray
});
$.download('/results/savepdf', data);
```